# VSCode Live Server - Changes URL to /undefined

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

Was using LiveServer no problem for quite some time, suddenly I go and refresh the page and it changes /index.html to /undefined. Nothing I do fixes it, if I erase the /undefined, it displays the proper page for a split second then returns to /undefined.

I have attempted to uninstall & restart VSCode then reinstall, unsure what to do from here.

Comment: For some reason it appears it has to do with the ports... this project opens port 5500 - which doesn't want to work but if a project opens as 5501, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you cannot use certain words in your JS code or it will ruin it.